# Yii2: Dynamic max value validation rules

Tags: validation, yii2

How to add customized validation for a field in yii2.?
Textbox value should not exceed a table field values from current model.
Is there any way to add new rule from controller?

Ex: `$model->f1` should be lessthan or equal to `$model->f2`.

I got some points with dynamicmodel. But i have only one field to check.

it should work on client side also.

is there anyway to add custom rule from controller or in activeform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your validation rules in model to ensure f1 value is <= f2.

```
[
  // other validation rules
  ['f1', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'f2', 'operator' => '<='],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use CompareValidator [compareValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator.html#$operator-detail) property  as :-

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
       // Your Validation rules as
        [
            'f2' ,
            'compare' ,
            'compareValue' => ArrayHelper::getValue($this , ['oldAttributes' ,'f1']),
            'operator' => '<=',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Model f1 value which is saved in database must be greater than f2 filled by user